# Иерархия ролей в базе

Tags: symfony

Кто-нибудь писал реализацию хранения в symfony динамических ролей в базе данных? Перерыл все исходники и мануалы, но так и не нашел, как это сделать. Может у кого-то есть идеи, как это можно сделать?

Comment: https://matthiasnoback.nl/2012/07/symfony2-security-creating-dynamic-roles-using-roleinterface/

Comment: Статья на основе [SecurityBandle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html)